# Using LINQ to fetch result from nested SQL queries

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql, dataset, linq-to-dataset

This is my first question and first day in Linq so bit difficult day for me to understand.
I want to fetch some records from database

i.e.

```
select * from tblDepartment 
where department_id in 
(
   select department_id from tblMap 
   where Guest_Id = @GuestId
)
```

I have taken two DataTable. i.e. tblDepartment, tblMap

Now I want to fetch this result and want to store it in third DataTable.

How can I do this.

I have been able to construct this query up till now after googling.

```
var query = from myrow in _dtDepartment.AsEnumerable()
            where myrow.Field<int>("Department_Id") == _departmentId
            select myrow;
```

Please provide me some link for learning `Linq` mainly for `DataTables` and `DataSets`.

**EDIT:**

I have got a very similar example **[here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/e5bb0c39-bc12-4803-a019-fa16f9b15f99/)** but i m still not able to understand how it is working.
Please put some torch on it.

I want to do this because I am already fetching data from database and dont want to send request again when I already have data. But I want to filter that data based on conditions.

Comment: if you are using linq to sql / linq to entities, you wont need data tables / data sets. everything will be in strongly typed objects

Comment: I am fetching a result from sql into DataTable then passing this result to user control which accepts datatable or dataset and then at that place in user control code i need to use some way to query that datatable. for this I want to use DataTable. Please provide some good resources as well to work with linq. I am a blank page in Linq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are attempting is not actual LINQ-To-SQL.  It is a common misunderstanding.  In LINQ-To-SQL you map some tables to entities in a simple way, then at run-time your LINQ query is translated by SQL by the framework and returned as your pre-defined strongly typed entity objects.  (I use "entity" as a descriptive term; nothing to do with Entity Framework.)  LINQ-To-SQL is something you do *instead of* ADO.NET.

What you are doing is a flavor of LINQ-to-object often called "LINQ-To-Dataset", which I use often.  The extension method `.AsEnumerable()` returns a DataTable's DataRows in an `IEnumerable<DataRow>` object, which is very handy.  However, with LINQ-To-DataTable, you either (A) won't have strongly typed objects, or (B) you are **taking responsibility for putting your data into strongly typed objects yourself**.   *After you've used ADO.NET* like you always have, LINQ-to-DataTable is a great way to get your data *out of* ADO.NET DataTables and into *something else*, whatever is consuming the data.

You LINQ query above will take your DataTable, which has already run against the DB, and return an `IEnumerable<DataRow>`, which is great.  Do:

After your LINQ statement, do:

```
For Each DataRow in query
    //Do your stuff
Next
```

If you really need a DataTable object in particular at this point, then [check this out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921.aspx).  But do you really need a DataTable?

- [Good intro to LINQ-To-DataSet](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2007/12/06/LINQToDataSetReallyCoolMakesDataSetDataTableMoreUsefulDemos.aspx) (sometimes called LINQ-To-DataTable)
- [Good explanation of LINQ-To-SQL](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx)

And I have to suggest a really great book about LINQ.  LINQ *rocks*.  In a .NET world that seems to have too much that we need to learn, LINQ is worth taking the time to really understand.  Get:  [LINQ In Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988169).

Comment: Thx for the information, What this will be called in this case. And how to work with both. i.e Linq and above given code. Is it using both linq syntax as well as some other thing. I dont know what to name it.

Comment: @Patrik: I think I will need a datatable as I have records with relationship of  one to many say result A then these many from A will be again mapped again as one to many sa result B i.e. 1-4 then these 4-*. And result are to be displayed on form with repeated result on behalf of first relation.All results of A are to be displayed and their corresp B's result are to be displayed. But they  should not be displayed on grid. They are to be displayed on form

Comment: I think my first link (that I just added) will be what you need then.  You'll use something like:  `Var boundTable = query.CopyToDataTable();`